# How does python property class instance work?

Tags: python

I have this

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import math
class myclass(object):

    def __init__(self,radius):
            self.radius = radius
    @property
    def area(self):
            print myclass.area,  type(myclass.area)
            return math.pi * ( self.radius ** 2)

    @area.setter
    def area(self,value):
           print myclass.area, type(myclass.area)
           pass

    @area.deleter
    def area(self):
           print myclass.area, type(myclass.area)        
           del myclass.area                


if __name__ == '__main__':

    c = myclass(5.4)
    c.area
    c.area = 65
    del c.area
```

This gives:

```
$ ./propertytest.py 
<property object at 0x7ff0426ac0a8> <type 'property'>
<property object at 0x7ff0426ac0a8> <type 'property'>
<property object at 0x7ff0426ac0a8> <type 'property'>
```

**Question:**

Look at the way property object `area` has been accessed: `c.area`. `area` appears on the right side of the dot operator. Which special method is used by the property object to bind the class instance object with the right instance method and compute the result? How do properties work?

Comment: You are using old-style classes. Add in the required `super(myclass, self).__init__()`.

Comment: @Wessie This inherits from object, and thus is a new-style class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Properties are descriptors. A descriptor is an instance of a class with `__get__`, `__set__` and/or `__delete__` method. Whenever python does `getattr`, `setattr` and `delattr`, if the instance does not have said attribute, and in the class there is a attribute with that name, that has the matching magic method, the magic method is called instead of the reading/writing/deleting the attribute.

The [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html) tells more on descriptors and also has this pure python emulation of builtin `property` type:

```
class Property(object):
    "Emulate PyProperty_Type() in Objects/descrobject.c"

    def __init__(self, fget=None, fset=None, fdel=None, doc=None):
        self.fget = fget
        self.fset = fset
        self.fdel = fdel
        if doc is None and fget is not None:
            doc = fget.__doc__
        self.__doc__ = doc

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        if obj is None:
            return self
        if self.fget is None:
            raise AttributeError("unreadable attribute")
        return self.fget(obj)

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        if self.fset is None:
            raise AttributeError("can't set attribute")
        self.fset(obj, value)

    def __delete__(self, obj):
        if self.fdel is None:
            raise AttributeError("can't delete attribute")
        self.fdel(obj)

    def getter(self, fget):
        return type(self)(fget, self.fset, self.fdel, self.__doc__)

    def setter(self, fset):
        return type(self)(self.fget, fset, self.fdel, self.__doc__)

    def deleter(self, fdel):
        return type(self)(self.fget, self.fset, fdel, self.__doc__)
```

Answer (score 1):

To make what is happening above a bit more explicit, let's get rid of the decorator syntax sugar:

```
import math
class myclass(object):

    def __init__(self,radius):
            self.radius = radius

    def getter(self):
            print myclass.area,  type(myclass.area)
            return math.pi * ( self.radius ** 2)

    # create a property object with "getter" as the getter, assigned to "area"
    area = property(getter) 

    # area.__get__ is now a method that wraps "getter"



    def setter(self,value):
           print myclass.area, type(myclass.area)
           pass

    # create a copy of the "area" object with "setter" as a setter, assign back to "area"
    area = area.setter(setter) 

    # area.__set__ is now a method that wraps "setter"



    def deleter(self):
           print myclass.area, type(myclass.area)        
           del myclass.area  

    # create a copy of the "area" object with "deleter" as a deleter, assign back to "area"
    area = area.deleter(deleter)

    # area.__delete__ is now a method that wraps "deleter"
```

Comment: The code gives an error when run. `AttributeError: can't set attribute
`

Comment: @abc Seems to be running correctly on my shell and in ideone: http://ideone.com/GmFfDm

Comment: @abc Here it is again with the code after the class definition: http://ideone.com/jpw2CT

Comment: @abc It *does* give me an error in Python 3: http://ideone.com/bYGBXB, but that's because your code is using the old syntax for `print`

Comment: @abc That's because you create a copy of the the `area` property object with an added setter using `area.setter(setter)`, but don't assign it back to `area`, so `area` is still the same old property object that only has a getter. You need `area = area.setter(setter)`. This is the same principle as  `a = "hello" LINEBREAK a + " world"` not changing the value of `a` at all. You'd have to do `a = a + " world"`.

Comment: Right. You see but the pydoc for property does not indicate that there is a return value for `deleter` , `setter` and `getter` methods.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35851/discussion-between-abc-and-asad)

Comment: @abc The docs do say that. To quote [this page](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property): *"A property object has getter, setter, and deleter methods usable as decorators that create a copy of the property with the corresponding accessor function set to the decorated function."*

Comment: I have that in my answer

Comment: @AnttiHaapala What are you referring to?

Comment: the "python emulation" for `property`, copied directly from docs.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala But I'm not "emulating" `property` at all, my answer still uses the native `property` type. All I'm doing is replacing the descriptor syntax with the more explicit one. Try actually reading the answer.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Sorry, replacing the **decorator** syntax, not "the descriptor syntax".

Comment: @Asad     # area.__set__ is now "setter" ,     # area.__get__ is now "getter" ,     # area.__delete__ is now "deleter" these comments are incorrect. This is because the property descriptor object is internally using these methods in its own __ get __, __ set __ and __ delete __ methods. So these methods and descriptor protocol methods are not the same.

Comment: @abc How so? <filler>

Comment: @abc **"This is because the property descriptor object is internally using these methods in its own __ get __, __ set __ and __ delete __ methods"**. Those methods do nothing but call the methods you've passed in , so I'm not sure what your point is. This is an implementation detail specific to the native `property` object: you can make your own descriptor object simply by doing `a = {} \n a.__get__ = getter \n a.__set__  = setter \n a.__delete__ = deleter`.

Comment: @Asad Exactly they are being used internally. Therefore they are not the same methods as the comments indicate. Someone reading them might get the impression that the methods in property object were simply replaced by the new methods, which is strictly speaking not the case.

Comment: @abc I think I see what you're saying. Does the edit address your concerns?

Comment: @Asad Nice. Thanks Asad!